# I couldn't make my first app

Tags: android-studio

So, beginner here and I have a problem with dropping the plain text widget into the layout. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

I cannot constrain the widget because the widget does not even show. I looked at various tutorials on how to bypass that but I have been unsuccessful. You may see that there is a render problem, missing accessibility label and failed to instantiate one or more classes[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yZe1.png). So, my question is, why is widget not showing and does it have to with the 3 messages that android studio threw at me?

**Edit 1:**
Mandatory: Based on the second answer I changed this code: "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" into this one: "base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar". With the second solution, I was able to drop my widgets into the layout screen. This is why I say that the answer half-helped me because I got forward with my project but lost my 'design' feature(the one alongside the 'blueprint'). Here are some photos that may help you understand my problem:

strings.xml
 [image: strings.xml]

AndroidManifest.xml
 [image: AndroidManifest.xml]

MainActivity.java
 [image: MainActivity.java]

As you can see, I don't have the design feature:
  [image: As you can see, I don't have the design feature]

Render Problem:
  [image: Render Problem]
Missing Constraints:
   [image: Missing Constraints] 
Missing Styles
[Missing Styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9IyA.png)

Comment: "I don't think the community should downvote a new user"  I think new users can spend the 2 minutes it takes to read the help page, not to mention all the prompts explaining how to ask a question that can be answered.  Based on your question, it seems you disagree.  You can go elsewhere or hire a consultant.  Or, try again to write a clear, concise, and specific question that we can answer, and one that may help others in the future.  This isn't a consulting service, it's a place where you learn and then go to teach others.  And yet, you couldn't be bothered to put your code in your question.

Comment: Hey Brad, I am sorry for my negligence. I am still trying to learn how to ask questions over here. You can be rest assured that I will read the help page going forward.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to the Android Community.
Now, regarding your error, here are few possible solutions which might work:-

- Go to Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle files.

**If the above solution does not work**

- Change the theme from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar in styles.xml file.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
Change the styles.xml as follows:-

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
</style>
```

There was a typo, b in Base should be capital

I hope this edit helps.

Comment: Regarding your first solution, it didn't help me at all because the same messages flared again. The second solution helped me go forward but took something away from me. I cannot fully illustrate in words, the slew of new problems. I also don't know how to attach pictures in the comments. I'll make a new post regarding the new problems. Can you check that out? I would be grateful.

Comment: @Shreeman Gautam, you can edit this question by including new errors, I will check that out and see if I can help with it, May I know if the gradle build is successful or not? If not please include the screenshots of the error message.

Comment: Also, please include the code of xml and java, it would be a great help.
Regards,
Sankalp

Comment: I have edited my questions as you have suggested. How can I know if a gradle build is successful (although I have included the screenshots of the error message)? Lastly, thank you for your help. I appreciate it!

Comment: @ShreemanGautam I have edited my answer please take a look, also one small advise:- Try not to change your original question text directly, rather place an Edit paragraph below it, Otherwise the other developers will not understand the context of the question and will downvote the question.
PS: I have not downvoted this question, rather I appreciate your efforts and have upvoted it. Regard's, Sankalp

Comment: Hey Sankalp, I appreciate your time and effort to help me. Turns out, it was a typo and now I have my design back. I have one question though, why did your solution work?  implemented it but I have no idea how it works. Thanks!

Comment: You are more than welcome, I'm glad I was able to help. Check Mark this answer as accepted, if it solved your issue.

 _@ShreemanGautam, I personally had this issue when I started with Android about a year ago, but it went away after updating android studio. Now what I can infer is Theme.AppCompat was an improvement to Base.Theme i.e. Base.Theme had some issue of backward compatibility that's why the android team revised it and changed it to Theme.AppCompat (however, this is not confirmed coz I personally used Base.Theme for a month or two and_  ( on limit the answer is contd in nxt comment)

Comment: (contd. from previous comment) _and I never faced an issue) so, what might be happening is, some of the components that you are using might be of legacy type and are not compatible with **Theme.AppCompat** and hence are not able to work with it, since those components are familliar with **Base.Theme** they are working fine with it. However, this is just my hypothesis, the real reason might be different. I hope this answer's your query. Best of luck with android development_ Regards, Sankalp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use same version in gradle `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, and `supportLibraryFunction`

Also check in project file of gradle has

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}
```

Hope this helps for you.

Comment: Can you guide me through all of this? Like, which files do I open to get to, let's say compileSdkVersion? I am a beginner in this and Java, for that matter.

Comment: Grateful for your time!

Comment: open **build.gradle(Module: app)** check `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and `dependencies` library has same version. Ex: `compileSdkVersion 27` `targetSdkVersion 27` `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` in dependencies also has version number of 27

Comment: Hey vijikrish, I checked and yes, all of the three things have the same version. I appreciate your guidance!